# Detect when all dice have stopped moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

This seems like such a simple problem but I'm having a hard time with it. I'm rolling some dice (`GameObject`s) and trying to detect when they all have stopped moving (so I can then calculate the score).

Here's what I've tried:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] _dice;

    public Vector3 _rollStartPosition;
    public float _rollForce;
    public float _rollTorque;

    bool anyDieIsMoving = false;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!anyDieIsMoving && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            RollDice();
    }

    void RollDice()
    {
        foreach (var die in _dice)
        {
            // Roll() adds force and torque from a given starting position
            die.GetComponent<Die>()
               .Roll(_rollStartPosition, Random.onUnitSphere * _rollForce, Random.onUnitSphere * _rollTorque);
        }

        StartCoroutine(CheckIfDiceAreMoving());

        // Calculate score and do something with it...
    }

    IEnumerator CheckIfDiceAreMoving()
    {
        foreach (var die in _dice)
        {
            var dieRigidbody = die.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (!dieRigidbody.IsSleeping())
            {
                anyDieIsMoving = true;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it immediately tries to calculate the score before all the dice have stopped moving (I discovered this by adding a bunch of `Debug.Log()` statements).

How can I wait for all the dice to stop moving before calculating the score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make `RollDice` a coroutine function then you can yield or wait for the `CheckIfDiceAreMoving` function to return with `yield return`. Even better, turn the `if (!dieRigidbody.IsSleeping())` into `while (!dieRigidbody.IsSleeping())` so that the `CheckIfDiceAreMoving` function will not exit until all dice stops moving. Also, check input in the `Update` function instead of `FixedUpdate` which is used to move `Rigidbody`.

This is the rafactored code:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] _dice;

    public Vector3 _rollStartPosition;
    public float _rollForce;
    public float _rollTorque;
    bool doneRolling = true;

    void Update()
    {
        if (doneRolling && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StartCoroutine(RollDice());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RollDice()
    {
        doneRolling = false;

        foreach (var die in _dice)
        {
            // Roll() adds force and torque from a given starting position
            die.GetComponent<Die>()
               .Roll(_rollStartPosition, Random.onUnitSphere * _rollForce, Random.onUnitSphere * _rollTorque);
        }

        //Wait until all dice tops moving
        yield return CheckIfDiceAreMoving();


        // Calculate score and do something with it...


        //Set doneRolling to true so that we call this funtion again
        doneRolling = true;
    }

    IEnumerator CheckIfDiceAreMoving()
    {
        foreach (var die in _dice)
        {
            var dieRigidbody = die.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            //Wait until all dice stops moving
            while (!dieRigidbody.IsSleeping())
            {
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good. I'm at work but I'll test when I get home. Thank you!

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you! One follow up question: Where I'm applying force and torque to the `Die`'s `RigidBody` in `Roll()`, wouldn't it make sense to put the calls to `Roll()` in a `FixedUpdate()`?

Comment: Well you are adding force to the rb once only so that really shouldn't matter. If you're adding force every frame then it should be done in the `FixedUpdate`. By the way, you can just call `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();` in your `RollDice` function then run the `foreach (var die in _dice)` loop and add your force. That should give you the-same thing as using `FixedUpdate`

Answer (score 1):

In **RollDice()**, it calculate score before getting status of **anyDieIsMoving**. I think you show move the calculate score to coroutine.

```
void RollDice()
{
    foreach (var die in _dice)
    {
        // Roll() adds force and torque from a given starting position
        die.GetComponent<Die>()
           .Roll(_rollStartPosition, Random.onUnitSphere * _rollForce, Random.onUnitSphere * _rollTorque);
    }

    StartCoroutine(CheckIfDiceAreMoving());

}

IEnumerator CheckIfDiceAreMoving()
{
    while(anyDieIsMoving){
        anyDieIsMoving = false;
        foreach (var die in _dice)
        {
            var dieRigidbody = die.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (!dieRigidbody.IsSleeping())
            {
                anyDieIsMoving = true;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }

    // Calculate score and do something with it...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll be testing out all the answers later today.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the other two answers have said, I would change `CheckIfDiceAreMoving()` in this way (using siusiulala's version):

```
while(anyDieIsMoving){
    anyDieIsMoving = false;
    foreach (var die in _dice)
    {
        var dieRigidbody = die.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (!dieRigidbody.IsSleeping())
        {
            anyDieIsMoving = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

As soon as one die is not moving, break out of the *for loop* as it is no longer relevant. The original code puts the *for loop* on pause and returns to it *at the same index* later.  Afterall, it's the *while loop* that we want coroutine'd.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll be testing out all the answers later today.